# Is the priority of some tags wrong?

Tags: bug, tags

I know, from my experience, that many users tag the wrong RDBMS. Something I have noticed, however, when fixing the tags is that the UI does not help them not tag the wrong one. Take, for example, the tag for SQL Server [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server). When typing out the tag's name it isn't actually the first tab option until you type the entirety of the tag's name.

[image]

Notice in this animated gif, that apart from `s`, `sql`, and `sql-server` the first tab option is [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), not [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server). I can understand this for the `sq`, my guess is that the [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) is used far more than [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), but once you get to `sql-` or at least `sql-s` I would except [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) to be the first tag choice, Certainly `sql-serve` should not be defaulting to [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql).

I don't doubt that this is the only one, but it feels to me that the priority is wrong here and could do with tweaking.

Comment: Order is given first by equality (what you typed is exactly the same as the tag name, synonyms don't count!) and later by number of questions. I don't have source for that, so you have to take my word for it.

Comment: So how does `sql-serve` =  `mysql` and *not* `sql-server` @Braiam ? If what you say is true, then `mysql` should have stopped being presented as the first tab option after `sql-`.

Comment: Because `sql-serve` ≊ `mysql-server` and # of mysql questions > # of sql-server questions.

Comment: But based on your statement "Order is given first by equality" then the equality of `sql-serve` against `sql-server` is higher, so `sql-serve` should present `sql-server` not `mysql-server`.

Comment: No. I said equality, not approximation. sql-serve != sql-server. If whatever you type is equal to any tag of the site, it will be appear first, otherwise is approximations ordered by number of questions with the tag.

Comment: Then, certainly the tags starting the same should be given thought. `sql-serve` should not be defaulting to `mysql`.

Comment: No, again. Unless is exactly the same tag, tags are ordered by popularity. It doesn't matter how many substrings both have in common.

Comment: Then we have a difference of opinion on what good UX is, @Braiam .

Comment: Well, I said it before, [I suck at UX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256114/people-dont-read-the-tag-excerpts-because-we-dont-swat-them-into-their-faces#comment835044_256114)

Comment: Heh, that post gets an upvote from me, @Braiam . :)

Comment: Braiam is right, I think, about the reason for why it works this way, and I am pretty sure that is by design, so this may end up needing to be re-stated as a [meta-tag:feature-request], instead of a [meta-tag:bug] report.

Comment: You could be right there, @TylerH . I have no problems with it being changed to a [tag:feature-request] though my personal opinion at the moment is it's a "bug".

Comment: Wait? That list is meant to be populated? [consider yourself lucky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjceh.png) (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353785/tag-suggestions-are-empty)

Comment: I found, as well, that it doesn't populate in meta when writing this question.

Answer (score 1):

[mysql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-server) is a synonym of [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql).

The search is matching against `sql-serve` in `mysql-server` and as it is more popular than [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) (through the synonym of `mysql`) it is listed first.

Comment: Huh, apparently Braiam indicated towards this in the comments, didn't see that. The point is, this isn't a _bug_ even if it doesn't work the way you'd expect it to.